# Google chart loading message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

I have the following script which works, but has one annoying issue:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartAjax);

    function drawChartAjax() {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'chart_json.aspx', 
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(data) { 
                drawChart(data); 
            } 
        });
    }

    function drawChart(json) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'User');
        data.addColumn('number', 'v');
        data.addRows(json.length);
        for(var j in json) {
            for(var k in json[j]) {
                data.setValue(parseInt(j), 0, k);
                data.setValue(parseInt(j), 1, json[j][k].v);
            }
        }
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart( document.getElementById('chart_div') );
        chart.draw(data, {width: 500, height: 300, is3D: true, title: 'Titles goes here'});
    }
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">header goes ehre</div>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <div id="footer">footer goes here</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that sometimes the chart can take a long time to appear for various reasons.  When this happens, the header loads, followed by the chart, followed by the footer.  This looks awful IMO.  IMO, the whole page should load, including the footer, and a flat "loading.." message should be displayed until the chart is ready to display itself, or an animated gif until the chart is ready.

How can I get the whole page to load and display a loading message until the chart is ready, instead of having the footer missing, then the footer suddenly appears once the chart has finished loading?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put the script at the bottom of the HTML file. This won't do a loading screen, but this will prevent the browser from blocking while the chart loads.

To get a loading effect, Google's Charts will overwrite the innerHTML of the `div` you're pointing it to, so you can keep a loading message in there (in whatever format you desire) and it will get overwritten when the chart loads.

Comment: I wouldn't argue if it was year 2003, but that's a bit too old-school. You can't assume that DOM is ready even when the script is at the end of the file. bozdoz has given the correct answer. Use $(function) causes the code inside to run after DOM is ready.

Answer (score 6):

I would use an onload handler to call the chart functions.  It should wait for the page to load, then add the chart.

```
$(function(){
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartAjax);
});
```

If this doesn't work, perhaps you could add a load handler to the footer div.

Answer (score 5):

Does Google Charts clear the chart div on load?

```
/* style.css */
.preloader {
    height:350px; background:url(../images/spinner.gif) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Set the height of the preloader equal to the resulting chart.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="chart_div"><div class="preloader">&nbsp;</div></div>
```

If it doesn't clear the preloader, you should add a callback on chart load to clear it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also take advantage of [Google Chart events](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events) to listen for when the chart has loaded and perform an action. It may require you to initially hide the chart container or overlay a loading icon. Example:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
            // Do something like ...
            /* $('#chart_div').css('visibility', 'visible'); // provided this was already hidden
            $('.loading-icon').hide(); // if it exists in your HTML */
        });
```