# Loading gif and animation with google charts

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I'm creating a dashboard using Google Charts and I need a way to include a loading gif or text that reads "Loading.." while my div or canvas loads with the chart. Also, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the charts to animate on start up as well as when values are updated.

Comment: Add some code please, and see **[Google chart loading message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068010/google-chart-loading-message)**.

Comment: This is two questions. It might seem silly to start a new question when they're both so small, but Stack Overflow is set up to reward one correct answer per question, so it helps both the person asking and the answerers to keep separate question separate.

Comment: Hey that link/question you provided was very helpful. But how about the case where you have multiple charts in several different divs? For example a page with 6 charts in 6 different divs.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search for 'loading gif' bought up a few results..

http://www.ajaxload.info/

http://preloaders.net/

Comment: I've decided to use this: http://codepen.io/MattIn4D/pen/LiKFC. My page has a button that loads charts and tables when clicked. I want to show the loading css while the charts load, that's all

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. It was literally 1 line of code. I wanted to do it with raw javascript and css. Its just a matter of grabbing the element and changing or 'setting' the class.

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").className = "stop_loading";
```